# Removing all options containing text from all select lists on a page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectlist

I'm trying to come up with a javascript/jquery method that will allow me to remove all select list options containing a particular text pattern on page load.

So far I have:

```
 $('select option:contains(\'foo\')')
```

Which returns me all the elements - how can I remove them? My initial thought was something along the lines of:

```
 $('select option:contains(\'foo\')').each().remove();
```

But this throws an exception.

Am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("select option:contains('foo')").remove();
```

jQuery functions automatically work on *all* selected elements. No need to use `each()` here.